# What is this data type in c#?

Tags: c#

I noticed this data type of `(local variable) (double freq, double power)[]` named `freqvsPower`

What does this mean? This isn't a 2D array, it seems to be an array of two types...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an array of [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-7.0), They are structures (value types) rather than classes

```
void Main()
{
    (double freq, double power)[] freqvsPower=new (double freq, double power)[]{};//array of valuetuple
    (double freq, double power) author = (1, 1);//single valuetuple object
    
    Console.WriteLine(freqvsPower.GetType());
}
```

[image]

what you are noticing is [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for `ValueTuple`

```
var vTuple0 = ValueTuple.Create(1d, 1d);//valuetuple object creation
ValueTuple<double,double> vTouple2 = new ValueTuple<double,double>(1,1);//valuetuple object
(double freq, double power) vTouple = (1, 1);//again valuetuple object - syntactic sugar
//above 3 declarations mean the same

//values from tuple can be access with Item1, Item2....so on
Console.WriteLine(vTouple.Item1);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples)

You're looking at an array of tuples with items named. You can ignore the names and Compiler will use `Item1`, `Item2` ... names.

Comment: `Tuple<...>` is a reference type, `ValueTuple<...>` (which is what this is) is a value-type. Just saying.

Comment: @Dai _"Tuple<...> is a reference type....which is what this is"_ - not sure what you point is.  The answer above mentioned _"Tuple"_ without an explicit mentioning of anonymous, struct or reference type.  It did not mention `Tuple<>` but rather posted a link to a page about _"Tuple types"_ including **anonymous tuples** (not `ValueTuple` which is a different beast all together) which is what the answer is.  There are 3 types of tuples in .NET.  Anony' tuples are code-gen'd as classes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/choosing-between-anonymous-and-tuple

Comment: @Deleted There's no such thing as "Anonymous tuples" in C# (I think you mean (the poorly named) _"anonymous types"_ feature in C# 3.0), and none of them use any Roslyn codegen features.